# Junit runs locally but not on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, jmockit

I have that JUnit test case:

```
private BusinessHandlerImpl mBusinessHandlerImpl();

@Test
public void testMyBusiness(){
   // some Expectations and test data preperation.
   Set<Long> lAllId = Collections.<Long>emptySet();
   List<Data> lAllData = mBusinessHandlerImpl.loadAllData(lAllId);
   Assert.assertNotNull(lAllData);
   Assert.assertTrue(lAllData.isEmpty());
}
```

the `BusinessHandlerImpl` `loadAllData` method class:

```
@Override
public List<Data> loadAllData(Set<Long> pAllId){
    List<Data> lResult = new ArrayList<>();
    // do some stuff to fill the list
    return lResult;
}
```

that test is very easy. It checks the logic with an empty list of id's.
The result should be an empty list of `Data`.

Well, that runs fine locally. But for some reason our jenkins is not successfully running that test.
Jenkins gives me an Assertion error at this place:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(lAllData);
```

per my understanding that's not possible. If an Exception would occur the `Assert` should not be reached.

has anyone ever seen the same and give me some hints what to do???

thx for your help

Stefan

Comment: Try to print out the result in all steps: `@Override
public List<Data> loadAllData(Set<Long> pAllId){
    List<Data> lResult = new ArrayList<>(); System.out.println(lResult);
    // do some stuff to fill the list System.out.println(lResult);
    return lResult;
}`

Comment: Where and how is `mBusinessHandlerImpl` initialized? Does it indeed go through the `loadAllData()` method provided here, and not though some override? Is there no other write into `lResult` in `loadAllData()`?

Comment: The code of your unit test seems flawed, `private BusinessHandlerImpl mBusinessHandlerImpl();` will not compile, where is the assignment of an instance - like `mBusinessHandlerImpl = new BusinessHandlerImpl()`?

Comment: sorry forgott that. it's done inside the setup method

Comment: Does it 'run fine locally' within Eclipse, via maven, or via some other way?

Comment: Clearly `Assert.assertNotNull(lAllData)` would fire if `// do some stuff to fill the list` would contain a `return null`, for example under some error condition depending on an external setup. What stuff is done there?